# Form Designing using bootstrap

Tags: html, css

how to make forms using HTML? [this is a form that takes character input one by one in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/564xt.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into Basic Bootstrap Form

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Basic form layout**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have three approaches, Here you can use both or as per your requirements.because of your structure of form i think so, you want to make it using table.

**1. Use Input in .**

```
 Using <input> element in all <td>s,

 <tr><td><input type="text"></td>....</tr>
```

Also You might want to resize the input to the size of it's td. ex.,

```
 input { width:100%; height:100%; }
```

**2. Use contenteditable='true' attribute. (HTML5)**

But if you want to use contenteditable='true' you might also want to save the appropriate values to the database. you can achieve this with ajax.

You can attach keyhandlers keyup, keydown, keypress etc to the . Also it is good to use some delay() with that events when user continuously types, the ajax event won't fire with every key user press. for example,

```
$('table td').keyup(function() 
{
 clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
 var wait = setTimeout(saveData, 500); // delay after user types
 $(this).data('timer', wait);
});

function saveData() 
{
  // ... ajax ...
}
```

**3. Append to when it is clicked.**

Add the input element in td when the is clicked, replace it's value according to the td's value. When the input is blured, change the td's value with the input's value. All this with javascript.